# Testing javascript client side

Tags: javascript, testing, client

Im looking for some javascript code testing like jasmine but I need to return testing results as a object not as html with int, does anyone know of any?

Comment: Would custom reporters help? http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_reporter.html

Comment: propably can help but how to turn off html interface?

Comment: you could remove it in boot.js by commenting out env.addReporter(htmlReporter);